# Reload/Refresh only a special div on current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have the following html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content one">Hello</div>
  <div class="content two">Sam</div>
  <div class="button">Click me</div>
</div>
```

The url of this page is dynamically created, something like this "www.mypage.com/sam". So I need to get the current url of this page for running my script.

Now I want to reload/refresh only the "content two" div at the current page by clicking the button. I tried something like this, but without success:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.content.two').load( url ".content.two" ); 
});
```

What's my fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$(".content.two").load(location.href + " .content.two");
```

Comment: You did not concatenate it, that was your mistake. Hope it helps

Comment: If you could mark this as a correct answer i might get my question asking ability back. I am not able to ask questions at the moment due to negative feedback on a single question.

Comment: I will do, but there is a time counter for accepting - I have to wait two more min ;) ...